# Some questions about Scanf

Tags: c, scanf

What's the differences between the next three codes.

1:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
}tree[100050];
/*
some codes
*/
int main()
{
    int tot;
    scanf("%d",&tot);
    int tmp;
    for(int i=0;i<=tot;++i){
        scanf("%d",&tmp);
        tree[i].data=tmp;
        insert(i,1);
    }
}
```

Wrong Answer

2:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
}tree[100050];
/*
some codes
*/
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int tmp;
    for(int i=0;i<=n;++i){
        scanf("%d",&tree[i].data);
        insert(i,1);
    }
}
```

Accepted

3:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
}tree[100050];
/*
some codes
*/
int main()
{
    int tot;
    scanf("%d",&tot);
    int tmp;
    for(int i=0;i<=tot;++i){
        scanf("%d",&tmp);
        tree[i].data=tmp;
        insert(i,1);
        tmp=0;
    }
}
```

Accepted

The first codes can not pass all tests, but next two codes can pass all tests.

The problem is here [POJS024](http://hzoi.openjudge.cn/shu/S024)。It is written in Chinese.
Input is a list of number which builds a Binary Sort Tree，the first number is the root.
Output the In-Order Traversal and the Post-Order Traversal。

Answer (score 5):

All three use wrong logic. You got lucky in the second and third, probably because `insert` has some special handling of values that are equal to 0.

The mistake in all three is that you are using

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;++i){
```

instead of

```
for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
             ^^^ Needs to be < not <=
```

If you had code to check the return value of `scanf`, you would have caught your error sooner.

```
if ( scanf(...) == 1 )
{
    insert(i,1);
}
```

That's why it's very important that you make a habit of checking the return value of `scanf` family of functions ALWAYS to make sure that you were able to read all data that you were expecting to.

Answer (score 2):

The problem (which actually exists in some sense in all three cases) is that you call `scanf()` one too many times because you're using a `<=` comparison in the `for` loop instead of the using the `<` comparison.  As a result the last call to `scanf()` actually fails. and you call `insert(i,1)` one more time than it should be called.

In example 1 that results in `tree[i].data` being set to the last value that was read into `tmp`, in examples 2 and 3 that value is left at zero.  Apparently the extra call to `insert(i,1)` doesn't cause a problem in that particular scenario.